# Oracle REGEXP_REPLACE uppercase replacement string

Tags: regex, oracle, replace

I am attempting to uppercase the replacement string from my reg expression without success:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('src=/i/uie_v2/js','(/uie_v2/)',upper('\1')) from dual
```

returns `'src=/i/uie_v2/js'`

I understand that upper cannot be used .. just showing as an example. Any ideas on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot do this directly, but you can take the string apart and rebuild it:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('src=/i/uie_v2/js','(.*)(/uie_v2/)(.*)', '\1') ||
  upper(regexp_substr('src=/i/uie_v2/js','(/uie_v2/)')) || 
  regexp_replace('src=/i/uie_v2/js','(.*)(/uie_v2/)(.*)', '\3')
from dual
```

I got the idea from an [OTN forums thread on REGEXP](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=623330).