# select regexp_replace('aaa_bbb', '(_.)', upper('\1')) from dual

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace

Using Oracle 11g

```
select regexp_replace('aaa_bbb', '(_.)', upper('\1')) from dual;
```

I want `'aaa_Bbb'`.

But, it returns `'aaa_bbb'`.

Why can't replace?

Comment: Not really the answer and I don't have an Oracle DB to try it at hand, but would '\U\1' instead of upper('\1') work?

Comment: No, it wouldn't, @makrom. It results in `aaa\U_bbb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upper execute earlier Regexp

```
select regexp_replace('aaa_bbb', '(_.)', upper(regexp_substr('aaa_bbb', '(_.)'))) from dual
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with

```
select regexp_replace('aaa_bbb', '(_.)', upper('\1')) from dual;
```

is that `upper` is executed before `regexp_replace`, effectively making it:

```
select regexp_replace('aaa_bbb', '(_.)', '\1') from dual;
```

So you need a different approach.

See the answer to [oracle regexp replace uppercase replacement string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726450/oracle-regexp-replace-uppercase-replacement-string)

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have to be *regular expressions* approach, then `substr + instr + initcap` might help.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'aaa_bbb' from dual)
  3  select substr(col, 1, instr(col, '_')) || initcap(substr(col, instr(col, '_') + 1)) result
  4  from test;

RESULT
-------
aaa_Bbb

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a direct method to convert by using `regexp_replace` but it's possible by `regexp_substr` in such a way :

```
with t(str) as
(
 select 'aaa_bbb' from dual
)
select concat( regexp_substr(str, '.*[_^]'), initcap( regexp_substr(str, '[^_]+$') ) )
       as "Formatted String"
  from t;


Formatted String
----------------
aaa_Bbb
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e97a9b2f79f74140959932afa092b1a1)</kbd>